# Margins around itemize in xltabular

Tags: margins, itemize, enumitem, xltabular

I am using xltabular for a table spanning multiple pages, and want to have bullet lists in some of the cells. As far as I understand, margins around itemize should be removed by using nosep, but this did not entirely work for me. I want the bullet list to start on the same height as the text in the neighboring cells, like those in the itemize* section in my example. How would I achieve that?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{K}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{c | L{3.2cm} | L{3.5cm} | K}

    \hline
    1 & filler & text &
    \begin{itemize*}[nosep,leftmargin=*,itemjoin={\newline}]
        \item inline items
        \item with an inserted newline almost look fine, but are indented weirdly 
    \end{itemize*}\\
    \hline
    2 & more & filler &
    \begin{itemize}[nosep,leftmargin=*]
        \item non-inline items
        \item are indented nicely, but have margins above and below them in the cell
    \end{itemize}\\
    \hline

\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

And the output:
[image: pdf output]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633000/134144 may be interesting.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you so much, that worked very well. I had tried the minipage approach before but couldn't get it to work properly.